# Is sorting happens in the DB Buffer cache or PGA in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, database-performance, sql-tuning

When the data is read from the discs or buffer cache and a sort is needed, is this sort done in the buffer cache(SGA) or PGA? If it is done in both, what is the difference between these sorts? And when & why it is done in the buffer cache or PGA?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Sorting is done in the [SQL work areas](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/memory.htm#CNCPT1242), which are mostly stored in the PGA. ([Here's a guide to tuning the work areas](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TGDBA/tune_pga.htm#TGDBA347); see also the [SORT_AREA_SIZE](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-A343E04E-B484-4791-8B01-12E182AA00C7.htm#REFRN10206) parameter.)

The [buffer cache](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/memory.htm#CNCPT1242) ([tuning guide](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TGDBA/tune_buffer_cache.htm#TGDBA294)) only really holds copies of data on disk (or data waiting to be written to disk) - no processing or work is done on the data in the buffer cache. It wouldn't be a very good cache if the data in it could be altered.

The main distinction in sorting behavior is whether you do it on-the-fly or beforehand (by creating an index - also done in PGA). If your data is already sorted, Oracle might read the index into the buffer cache - I'm not clear on that part - but the query will obviously be much faster.